# ScrollView over CollectionView but page outside collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am trying to utilize scrollView over collectionView, however, I have noticed recently some applications have scrollview over superView, which is not bound to collection View. I have attached the image to give a better picture. I am just curious as of how this can be achieved? Currently I have a scrollView which gets added to collection SubView. It would be nice to have this feature figured out.

[image]